# Chaincode events are bugged in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

Currently chaincode events in hyperledger will only raise duplicate events n number of times, where n is the number of chaincode events in a block and the event raised is the first event in the block.

```
  const profileRegId = this.event_hub.registerChaincodeEvent(request.chaincodeId, "Profile Added", event => {
    this.event_hub.unregisterChaincodeEvent(profileRegId);
    em.emit(event.payload);
  });
```

Above is how we are calling the registerChaincodeEvent function in our node application.

```
createEvent(APIstub, "Profile Added", profile)
```

Above is how we implement in the chaincode.

Is there a way to raise this as a bug with hyperledger myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure of opening a new bugs or submitting issues into Hyperledger Fabric is fairly simple, you need to register your linux foundation id ([read here the details](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/CONTRIBUTING.html)) and login into https://jira.hyperledger.org/, once done you can open an issue.

While from your description it's not really clear/obvious there is an issue, if you have n valid transactions each has created an event not sure whenever it was expected to have only single notification. Also please note, since release of v1.1.0 of Fabric there is a new event delivery service: [FAB-7069](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-7069) and here some [docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.1/examples/events/eventsclient) about it.

However, if you still think there is a bug or possible improvement, please submit [JIRA](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-7069).

Comment: So within a block, youll have 5 different CCevents, when the block is confirmed only the first CCevent is sent up to the node layer but repeated 5 times.